# AWS equivalent of Azure Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, azure-service-fabric

I don't want to get into a discussion about AWS vs Azure but I am trying to figure out how to set up the equivalent of an Azure Service Fabric Cluster on AWS.

I currently set up an environment in Azure by creating a Service Fabric Cluster which creates the virtual machines/nodes, load balancer and anything else that is needed.  I then have a visual studio project with a fabric project and a service project which i deploy to the cluster. I'd like to write my services in Visual Studio utilizing C#.

If I wanted to migrate this to AWS or set up a similar environment in AWS what do I create?  There seems to be a lot of different options but am confused as to whether i need to create the EC2 virtual machines myself and then the cluster and load balancer manually?

I am not sure if Elastic Beanstalk is needed or the easiest steps to create a microservice environment that I can deploy .NET apps from VS.

Thanks for any help/clarification.

Comment: i'm not sure, but please take a look on this manual:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services#containers-and-container-orchestrators
AWS - App Mesh 
Azure - Service Fabric Mesh
Description: Fully managed service that enables developers to deploy microservices applications without managing virtual machines, storage, or networking.

Comment: You could also look at https://istio.io/ and https://dapr.io/

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to keep the same application and deployment model, there is a [doc from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-standalone-create-infrastructure) that outlines the necessary steps for deploying Service Fabric on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably make more sense to use AWS Co-pilot or AWS CDK if you're migrating to AWS.